# unable to search tagged documents in SharePoint 2013/

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-results, tags

we tagged documents using the "tags and notes" option, as per the below screen shot.i am not able to find the document using Tag name.
[image]
I also enabled the "Search, Refine, Query, Retrieve" options for the Tags managed property, ran full crawl. but still i am not able to search the tagged documents with tag name.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, the "Tags and Notes" feature was officially deprecated in SharePoint 2013. If you use a MMS field on the list or library or apply Enterprise Keywords to the document or item, that will show in Search Results. It should show after a crawl in the Tags refiner.